# Django models, 2 foreign keys, object logic

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-3.7

(Capitalized the objects within the process).

> Is this considered legal, my goal is to have 3 individual objects (the
>   reasoning behind this is to allow me to assign a specific school +
>   major to specific professors). When a user is to select a SCHOOL, I
>   want my website to pull the MAJORS that specifically correspond to
>   that SCHOOL, and when they select a MAJOR, I want the specific
>   PROFESSORS to display.

Logical connection between the objects below (business rules)

> The SCHOOL needs to be a many-to-many relationship with MAJOR:
>
> - One SCHOOLS can have MANY Majors
> - One Major can have MANY SCHOOLS
>
> The PROFESSOR
>
> - a PROFESSOR can work at ONE SCHOOL, and teach ONE MAJOR
> - a Major can be taught by MANY PROFESSORS, at MANY SCHOOLS

So my difficulty is writing out the logic of the models to ensure all conditions are met, the information set before the rules is the experience I want my users to have when it comes to information pulled from the database to the website, and the logic below it.

```
from django.db import models

    class Professor(models.Model):
        School = models.ForeignKey(School , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        Major = models.ForeignKey(Major , on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Major(models.Model):
        Major = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        School = models.ForeignKey(School , on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class School(models.Model):
        School = models.Charfield(max_length=50)
```

Also, if you have any recommendations on making this logic more clear, I would grately appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using many-to-many fields for the relationship between schools and majors. I would add it onto the school since I personally think about it as "Schools have many majors" more frequently than "Majors are taught at many schools" but both would be fine.

Also, set the text fields to be something like `name` since that's what the text field represents: not the school/major, but rather the name of the school/major. Other than that, your logic looks good

```
from django.db import models

class Major(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True)

class School(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=50, db_index=True)
    majors = models.ManyToManyField(Major)

class Professor(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    major = models.ForeignKey(Major , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Once you've got this, you can grab major objects and add them to schools

```
major = Major.objects.get(name='Physics')
school = School.objects.get(name='Harvard')
school.majors.add(major)
```

...or grab schools and add them to majors via reverse-lookup (the "_set" attribute):

```
school = School.objects.get(name='Harvard')
major = Major.objects.get(name='Physics')
major.school_set.add(school)
```

Professors would be created without the ManyToMany relationships

```
school = School.objects.get(name='Harvard')
major = Major.objects.get(name='Physics')
Professor.objects.create(school=school, major=major)
```

Documentation reference on ManyToManyField: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: thanks you so much for the clear explanation! I had a question on regards to the last piece of code, so when adding the schools and majors, the school=school, and major=major, does this mean that inside the database I would literally see the name of the major and the school, or would they be the unique ID of the major and school which would be referencing to the major and school objects.

Comment: It would be stored within the database as the unique ID of the school object. For example, if you used the ORM to find `professor.school` you would receive the django School object that that professor belongs to. You could also do `professor.school_id` (a field that Django automatically generates) to get the numeric ID of the school. Finally, you could also access `professor.school.name` to get the name of the school (same goes for `professor.major.name`)

Comment: Ok so just to make sure im on right page, when looking at Professor.objects.create(school=school, major=major), I can think of it as the unique ID that a major represents and unique ID that a school represents is being assigned to the Professor classes school and major Foreignkeys within the database.

Comment: Yepp, exactly right. By default the field within the database is the field name plus "_id". For example, you could drop into a SQL shell and run `SELECT * FROM myapp_professor WHERE school_id=1;` and expect a result if there are professors assigned to the school that has an ID of 1